# Can't access to docker mongo without being root

Tags: mongodb, docker, permissions

I just installed docker and I could run a mongodb image in a container, without `sudo`. The port exposed is 27017.
I'm now trying to access it from a shell running on the host, but it works only with

```
sudo mongo --port 27017
```

I don't want to use `sudo`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

yes, but i think you're not taking the right approach.

if you're running mongodb in a docker container, you shouldn't be running the `mongo` shell from your host. you should be running it from your container.

for example, if your docker container is named `mydb`, you can do this:

`docker exec -it mydb mongo`

this will execute the `mongo` shell in the `mydb` container and give you "interactive" and "terminal emulation" (the `-it` params) so you can work as if you had the mongo shell directly on your computer.